# How should I type these objects in typescript so that certain properties are restricted to objects with different ids?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am relatively new to typescript and need some advice on how best to type an object structure like the one below. I want to be able to specify which item ids are allowed to be in a section based on a section id.

I realize this question might be vague, but really what I am looking for is for someone to point me in the right direction. If I need to totally re-type this object in a different way using some other typescript syntax, that is fine too. At this point, I am not sure what to Google or what I need to study about typescript to understand the best way to type an object like this.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
type ItemBase = {
  common: string | number
}

type Item = ItemBase & ({
  id: 'item1',
  custom1: string
} | {
  id: 'item2',
  custom1: number,
  custom2: string,
})

type SectionBase = {
  common: string | number
}

type Section = SectionBase & ({
  id: 'section1',
  items: {
    [key in Section1ItemIds]: Item
  },
} | {
  id: 'section2',
  items: {
    [key in Section2ItemIds]: Item
  },
})

type Section1ItemIds = 'item1';
type Section2ItemIds = 'item1' | 'item2';

type Group = {
  sections: {
    [key in Section['id']]: Section
  }
}

const group: Group = {
  sections: {
    section1: {
      id: 'section1',
      common: '',
      items: {
        item1: {
          id: 'item1',
          common: '',
          custom1: ''
        }
      }
    },
    section2: {
      id: 'section2',
      common: 0,
      items: {
        item1: {
          id: 'item1',
          common: '',
          custom1: ''
        },
        item2: {
          id: 'item2',
          common: '',
          custom1: 0,
          custom2: ''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const sectionIds = Object.keys(group.sections) as Array<keyof typeof group.sections>;
const sectionId = sectionIds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sectionIds.length)]
const section: Section = group[sectionId];

const getItemIds = (): (keyof typeof section.items)[] => {
  switch(section.id){
    case 'section1': return ['item1'];
    case 'section2': return ['item1','item2'];
  }
}
```

Comment: You *might* refactor your types to something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wy48Km).  But I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish with everything starting with `sectionIds`.  Your `section` definition looks like a typo, and I don't know what return type you're expecting from `getItemIds()`.  The type `keyof typeof section.items` isn't the type you want it to be.  Could you clarify exactly what the expected call signature of that function is supposed to be?

Comment: And while you're at it, it might be worth it to [edit] the question to remove the parts about how you want help (this normally goes without saying) and add clarifications of the type constraints you're trying to enforce instead of leaving it completely up to human beings parsing the code.